# Not able to create a table in netezza

Tags: database, netezza

I am new to `Netezza`,

I have a Physical Machine which is installed with Ubuntu 14.04. In Ubuntu 14.04, I have installed vmware player and on top of it I created netezza virtual host.

The above process is successful and I am able to login to netezza. Used below commands to connect to netezza.

```
Command 1: nzsql -u admin -pw password

SYSTEM.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> create database test;
```

and I am able to create database

```
SYSTEM.ADMIN(ADMIN)=>\c test
```

The above steps worked perfectly but when i tried creating a table by using below

```
TEST.ADMIN(ADMIN)=>create table users(name varchar(20));
```

it hangs up without any error or proceeding further:

Any help could be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: In your example your prompt indicates that you are not actually connected to the TEST database. At the Linux prompt as the nz user what is the output of nzstate?

Comment: Sorry my bad i pasted wrong one. Now corrected

Comment: I tried starting the netezza by using nzstart. Here is the warning which i am getting. nzstart: Warning: system did not go online after 600 seconds.

Comment: [nz@netezza ~]$ nzstate
System state is 'Discovering'.

Answer (score 3):

When you see a state of "Discovering" this tells you that the system is trying to boot and bring online the SPU VM, which provides the backed MPP processing.  This state is normal for a few minutes in the nzstart process, but not if it hangs there forever.

When running the Netezza emulator you may find yourself in a situation where the client VM that represents the SPU in the Netezza host VM gets into a confused state.

This will happen to me from time to time when I hibernate the VM.  The following process usually clears it up for me.

```
[nz@netezza ~]$ nzstop

Warning: nzstop does not stop SPU virtual machines!
If you want to stop them, use the following command:
     nzpush -all power off

[nz@netezza ~]$ nzpush -all power off
Powering off SPUs spu0101 ...Domain spu0101 destroyed

 done.


[nz@netezza ~]$ nzpush -all power on
Powering on SPUs spu0101 ...Domain spu0101 started

 done.
[nz@netezza ~]$ nzstart
nzstart: Warning: Using user-specified topology: /nz/nse/initTopology.cfg

(startupsvr) Info: NZ-00022: --- program 'startupsvr' (10693) starting on host 'netezza' ... ---
[nz@netezza ~]$ nzstate
System state is 'Online'.
```

If this does not work, then I usually escalate it with:

```
[nz@netezza ~]$ su - root
Password:

#############################
# current IP: 192.168.118.111
#############################

[root@netezza ~]# shutdown -r now
[root@netezza ~]#
Broadcast message from nz@netezza
        (/dev/pts/1) at 14:58 ...

The system is going down for reboot NOW!
```

After the reboot, the system should automatically start the database service. I then let "watch nzstate" run until it shows as "Online." Be patient while the system shows as "Discovering" here. Depending on the speed of your system it may be 5 minutes or more.